# Making a link inside a non-ajaxed div ajaxable with Ajaxify.js

Tags: jquery, href, page-refresh, history.js

Apologies for the confusing title, I'll try to explain it a bit better here..

I'm using [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) & [ajaxify-html5.js](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) to load the contents of my website into the main div while keeping an mp3 player playing music in another one that isn't being ajaxed so that the music doesn't stop on page changes.

It's set up like this..

`<div id="player">This div has the music player and other info about the music currently playing`

`<div id="main">Everything else goes in here, all content is loaded via ajax`

This all works just fine but I've run into a little problem that i'm hoping somebody here can help with.

In the `player` div I have info about the music currently playing.

Track Title, Track Artist etc

The Track Artist is also an href link that opens up a page about that artist but because it's located in the non-ajaxed  div it is reloading the whole site when the link is clicked.

So my question.

Is there someway of writing a function for a particular css element `.artist-name` for example, that will force it to load the link with ajax even though the css element holding the link is located in the non-ajaxed div?

So in effect any link on my site that I attached `.artist-name` to would always load with ajax no matter where it was on the page.

If this is possible does anybody have any suggestions on how I would go about writing this function into the ajaxify.js code?